# Separate array and apply getDay() function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to separate the array like this:

```js
 var cars = ['2022-12-1', '2022-12-2', '2022-12-3', '2022-12-4'];
       
 for(var i = 0; i < cars .length; i++){
   cars = cars [i];

   console.log(cars )

  }
```

It returns the first date, but I intended it to return all of them like this:

> 2022-12-1
>
> 2022-12-2
>
> 2022-12-3
>
> 2022-12-4

I want to separate the array so that I can number the days

Comment: Well, `cars = cars [i];` completely replaces your array with the first element. Why not simply `console.log(cars[i])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let cars = ['2022-12-1', '2022-12-2', '2022-12-3', '2022-12-4'];

for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  console.log(cars[i]);
}
```